# Can't connect asynchronously to opcua server

Tags: python, async-await, opc-ua

I'm trying to get a value of a node in my OPCUA server.

I'm using `asyncua` on a windows 10 x64 computer.
The server is on a PLC.

When I write this in a normal task it works

```
client = Client("opc.tcp://192.168.1.88:4840")
# client.max_chunkcount = 5000 # in case of refused connection by the server
# client.max_messagesize = 16777216 # in case of refused connection by the server
client.connect()
```

But when I use the basic example using an async function with the await the line,

```
await client.connect()
```

Returns a `timeoutError` with `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` but nothing else to explain why it doesn't work.

I would've kept trying without the the `await` but when I try to get my value with `client.nodes.root.get_child([...])` the returned value prints `<coroutine object Node.get_child at 0x000002C38EE45E40>` (when it should be a simple integer or boolean) and I don't know what to do with that so I guess I should keep going with the examples.

Do you have any idea why `await client.connect()` return this exception ?

I also tried with 2 different (and built under different langages) opcua clients just to be sure it wasn't the server that was broken. And the clients can connect properly.

---

EDIT: in case that helps, the console gives :

```
disconnect_socket was called but connection is closed
close_session was called but connection is closed
close_secure_channel was called but connection is closed
disconnect_socket was called but connection is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 490, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OPCgpt.py", line 28, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(connect_to_opc_server())
  File "Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "OPCgpt.py", line 12, in connect_to_opc_server
    await client.connect()
  File "Python311\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 287, in connect
    await self.open_secure_channel()
  File "Python311\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 374, in open_secure_channel
    result = await self.uaclient.open_secure_channel(params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Python311\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 315, in open_secure_channel
    return await self.protocol.open_secure_channel(params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Python311\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 232, in open_secure_channel
    await asyncio.wait_for(self._send_request(request, message_type=ua.MessageType.SecureOpen), self.timeout)
  File "Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 492, in wait_for
    raise exceptions.TimeoutError() from exc
TimeoutError
```

---

EDIT 2 : Someone asked me to post my code for people to be able to reproduce it. It's very simple so the bug is pretty odd. Someone on github mentionned that I may be blocking the eventloop but I didn't go too far off from [freeopcua's examples](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/tree/master/examples)..

```
import asyncio
from asyncua import Client

async def connect_to_opc_server():
    # Créez un client OPC UA
    client = Client(url="opc.tcp://192.168.1.88:4840")
    # client.max_chunkcount = 5000
    # client.max_messagesize = 16777216
    client.name = "Re_Shoes"

    try:
        # Connexion au serveur OPC UA
        await client.connect()

        # Lister tous les nœuds enfants du nœud racine (Object)
        root_node = await client.get_root_node()
        print("root node is: ", root_node)

    finally:
        # Déconnexion du serveur OPC UA
        await client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(connect_to_opc_server())
    loop.close()
```

This is my main code but I have tried many variations of this.

Comment: Didi you try the (example provided in the README)[https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio#client-class]? Also please include full code snippets (imports...)

Comment: @MatteoZanoni not on the server side, but on the client I'm always stuck at `await client.connect()` regardless of the example..

Comment: @MatteoZanoni I have tried changing `max_chunkcount` and `client.max_messagesize` because I struggled but it didn't change too much the situation..

Comment: I can only suggest using a gui tool like [FreeOpcUa/opcua-client-gui](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-client-gui) to verify your connection string is correct.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni I tried, I used with UaExpert and Opc.Ua.SampleClient (from OPC foundation) and they can connect properly. However the [FreeOpcUa gui from freeopcua github](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-client-gui) can't connect either

Comment: What is your setup? Are you running Linux/Windows/WSL/Mac? Is the OPC-UA server installed on your computer?

Comment: @MatteoZanoni I'm using asyncua on a windows 10 x64 computer. The server is on a PLC (so I don't have control on its settings). I'm connected with an ethernet cable.

Comment: The code looks good, I tried the same using the `uaserver --populate` command provided by asyncua (that starts a test OpcUa server on localhost) and I can connect properly using the same code as yours

Comment: @MatteoZanoni So the code works locally with uaserver.. Man it's a weird bug

Comment: Post a [mre]. Did you properly implement an asyncio event loop, calling the ```asyncio.run()``` for example?

Comment: @relent95 I have posted my whole code. It doesn't add too much but it does show the event loop. In all my attempts, I've never modified the eventloop part of the code (mostly because I'm not familiar with it) so it comes from the [libraries example](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/simple-client-server-xml/client_minimal.py). And in all the [different examples](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/tree/master/examples) I'm blocked at the connect() method.

Comment: Did you check the firewall? Maybe Python.exe is blacklisted?

Comment: @Schroeder You know I didn't think of that and had a lot of hope but it sadly didn't work... I also tried to enable explicitly the 4048 port but it did nothing too.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni turns out the problem came from the `security_policy`' Nonce. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back&forth I found that the issue came from the `Nonce` being empty.

If you dive into the library the `Nonce` is created in the `open_secure_channel()` method when you call the `connect()` function.
If you call the `connect()` method without specifying a `security_policy` the nonce size will be `0` (`b''` on windows and apparently `None` and some other platforms) and as I've seen in [another github post](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/issues/393#issuecomment-274774487), some servers do not like empty nonce string…

So to solve this problem with the `asyncua` lib I added this code before the `connect()` method and it solved my issue, I can now connect to the server.

```
client.security_policy.secure_channel_nonce_length = 8
def signature(self, data):
    return None
fixed_signature = types.MethodType(signature, CryptographyNone)
client.security_policy.asymmetric_cryptography.signature = fixed_signature
```